# "SadTalker" is running solely on my CPU instead of utilizing the GPU

Tags: rendering, huggingface, stable-diffusion

"SadTalker", an extension of stable diffusion, is running solely on my CPU instead of utilizing the GPU

I am using two arguments in the 'webui-user.bat' file: --medvram and --disable-safe-unpickle. It doesn't work without the --disable-safe-unpickle argument. However, txt2img is using the GPU normally. I have an AMD RX 580 8Gb." How can I solve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you manage to get anywhere with this?